# Mutual Exclusion using wait, synchronized, interrupt and notify

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify, mutual-exclusion

There are two threads. One is manipulating x and the other is displaying x. How can I use synchronized, interrupt, wait and notify to have mutual exclusion. The image shows this.

[Execution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSCWP.png)

I have came up with this solution but iam not sure if its correct.

Write

```
synchronized(x){
    x = x + 1;
    notify();
    try{
        wait();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
}
```

Read

```
synchronized(x){

    try{
         wait();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already used `synchronized(x) {}` closure to make sure this is not going to happen. What you are doing is correct. If your statements are in a separate method, you can also make your method synchronized so that it will not get affected until it gets out of this method.

```
public synchronized void doSmth() {
    //do smth;
}
```